# Calculate Load time in react for every route change

Tags: reactjs, routes, navigation, window, react-router-dom

I was trying the below calculation using

```
window.performance
```

object but this is not working for every route change. Can someone help me out to do the same.

My example:
`const loadTime = (window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic, every time routes change, you will have load time in loadTime state. Before, you should "npm install react-router-dom" in your folder terminal

```
import {useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
import {useEffect, useEffect} from 'react';


function App() {
const location = useLocation();
const currentRoute = location.pathname;

const getLoadTime = ()=>{
    const [loadTime, setLoadTime]= useState(null);
    const lt =
    (window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd -
      window.performance.timing.navigationStart) /
    1000;

    setLoadTime(lt);
}

useEffect(() => {
    getLoadTime();
}, [currentRoute]);

return (
    <div></div>
)
    
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I tried this code, but this is not giving new results based on route change. Instead it gives same duration as complete web page loading.